# New to OCaml finding index of element in a list

Tags: list, recursion, indexing, ocaml

I am learning OCaml and one of my practice problems I've given myself is to find the index of an element in a created list. So far I thought I had it but I've been rewriting this code block for ages and can't seem to get why the return values are incorrect.

```
let rec indexer_helper list element index pos found= 
match l with 
        []      ->  if (found = false) then
                        (-1)
                    else
                        index

    |   (h::t)  ->  if (h = e) then
                        index = pos
                        pos = pos + 1
                        indexer_helper t element index pos true
                    else
                        pos = pos + 1
                        indexer_helper t element index pos found;;

let rec indexer list element = indexer_helper list element 0 0 false;;
```

**Edit**: Problem solved. Issue was I forgot to use let statements when "changing" the immutable variables.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield is spot on. You could also ask yourself what is this `e` in the line `if (h = e) then`.

Comment: Please keep the original question, so that the answers make sense for future readers. The stackoverflow way to tell that your problem is solved is to accept an answer, which you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using your imperative reflexes a little too much here. These OCaml lines:

```
index = pos
pos = pos + 1
```

are computing Boolean values, not assigning values to variables. You can't assign a value to a variable (as such) in OCaml. Variables are immutable. The idiomatic way to write these lines in OCaml is something like:

```
let index' = pos in
let pos' = pos + 1 in
index_helper t element index' pos' true
```

There are other errors here, but this strikes me as the thing to figure out first.